# typedef и пользовательский тип

Tags: c++

В чем разница между typedef struct/class и пользовательским типом, созданным с помощью struct/class? Да, я понимаю, что typedef не создаёт новый тип, а делает всего лишь дополнительное имя для данного типа, но все таки, неужели создание типа так невыгодно?
typedef:

```
    typedef struct {
        int   size;
        int * massive;
    } MyStr;
```

Тип:

```
    struct MyStr{
        int   size;
        int * massive;
    };
```

Comment: Пример кода добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut ,Добавил.

Comment: В умелых руках эта штука сокращает длину кода, в неумелых - отличное средство запутать себя и других, которые потом вынуждены долго разбираться и что же здесь такого понаписано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Си++ разницы особой нет, разница есть в чистом Си. И в Си++ это используется, скорее, как пережиток Си.
В языке Си есть 4 типа пространств имен:
1) Метки (используется в конструкциях goto)
2) Тэги (имена структур, объединений и перечислений)
3) Члены структур и объединений
4) Все остальное (имена функций, объектов, констант и все typedefы).

Так же стандарт Си требует ([C11 6.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3)) раздельное пространство имен для каждой из этих категорий. Ну и все компиляторы и IDE в целом поддерживают этот стандарт. То есть, все эти элементы создаются в разных пространствах имен. Поэтому, например, такой код

```
struct myStruct {};
myStruct str;
```

не скомпилируется компилятором Си (но скомпилируется Си++), потому что тип myStruct находится в раздельном пространстве имен (не в том, в котором создается переменная str). Что бы такой код работал, str нужно объявлять так:

```
struct myStruct str;
```

Что бы не писать слово struct перед каждым объявлением переменной можно использовать прием с typedef. Т.к. все, что объявлено через typedef помещается в более общее пространство имен (в то же, где и все остальные объекты), то теперь нет необходимости писать слово struct перед каждым объявлением.

Comment: Вот теперь понятно. Я часто читаю коды программ на форумах и не редко встречаю данные, проженные, коды на c++.

Answer (score 0):

Оба ваши примера эквиваленты, они объявляют два разных одинаковых типа. Объявления в виде `typedef class/struct/union/enum` пришли из Си и поддеживаются в Си++ для совместимости. Так как большое количество старых отлаженых библиотек написано на Си.

Comment: Насколько я помню, в Си не было классов, так что `typedef class` точно не оттуда.

Comment: @rudolfninja Речь идет о Си++ и о том, что **форма** объявления `typedef ...` пришла из Си. Так как Си++ позволяет объявлять классы, то логично что это можно делать в сишной форме `typedef class`

Comment: Логично. Не правильно понял вашу мысль. Извиняюсь.